# Как в Unity вычислить скорость объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Если его движение сделано на `transform.position = Vector3.Lerp();`

Answer (score 2):

`Vector3.Lepr()` имеет три парметра:

1. `a` - Начальное значение
2. `b` - Конечное значение
3. `t`  - Значение, используемое для интерполяции между `a` и `b`.

скорость можно вычеслить таким образом:`(b - a) * t`